# Missing packages in github.com/grpc-ecosystem/go-grpc-middleware upgrading from v1 to v2

Tags: go, grpc, go-grpc-middleware

Migrating from v1 to v2 in github.com/grpc-ecosystem/go-grpc-middleware and didn't see
`muB := grpc_testing.NewMutexReadWriter(b)`

Link for old package: - https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/grpc-ecosystem/go-grpc-middleware@v1.4.0/testing#MutexReadWriter

Migrating github.com/grpc-ecosystem/go-grpc-middleware from v1 to v2,
need suggestion where i can find NewMutexReadWriter struct?

Comment: Maybe it wasn't needed by the package? It's trivial to implement where it is needed

Comment: @JimB, can you please elaborate more on it?

Comment: elaborate how? I don't use or maintain that package, so I can't say why it's not in the current version, but if there's no reference to the type then it's apparently not required.